# Remove space in column name for 10000 columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 10000 columns with space in it. I want to remove all spaces in all 10000 columns name.

Input: `the first column name`.

Output: `thefirstcolumnname`

---

What I tried:

```
select 'EXEC sp_rename '''+mytable+'.['+column_name+']'',''['+column_name+']'','''+replace(column_name,' ','')+'''' 
from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '% %'
```

However, it does not work. I suspect I need some changes in `column_name`, but I am not sure how.

Error: `Invalid column name 'table name'.` What does this suggests?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Your query produces a string (or actually a result set with one string per row).  Do you ever execute the string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried. The error info is updated.

Comment: If it's only 100 columns why not do each one manually?

Comment: @DanBracuk - Looks like that comment triggered a 100 fold increase in the problem.

Comment: Can down voters explain where I can improve the questions?

Comment: The ramifications for this are far wider than the column name. You will need to update every single query that touches every single table. You may also be prevented from doing this to some columns if you have schemabinding going on.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename '''+QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+'.'+QUOTENAME(column_name)+''','''+REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '')+''',''COLUMN'''
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%'
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'your table name here';
```

Comment: I used this script, but the new table seems has not changed.

Comment: @JohnHass try now I jus tmade a change there was a bug in it

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to generate those queries. Copy (and review) and run the contents of the third column.

```
SELECT
   ta.name, co.name
    ,replace(replace(replace(replace('EXECUTE sp_rename ''<schemaName>.<tableName>.[<columnName>]'', ''<fixedColumnName>'', ''column'''
   ,'<schemaName>', schema_name(ta.schema_id))
   ,'<tableName>', ta.name)
   ,'<columnName>', co.name)
   ,'<fixedColumnName>', replace(co.Name, ' ', ''))
 from sys.tables ta
  inner join sys.columns co
   on co.object_id = ta.object_id
 where co.name like '% %'
 order by
   ta.name, co.name
```

Comment: For admin-level stuff like this, I strongly recommend generating the script, reviewing it, and then running the reviewed script.

Comment: Understand. I am running on a duplicate table for testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t1 ([col] int,[another col] int,[yet another col] int);
create table t2 ([also a col] int,[col] int);
```

---

```
select      'exec sp_rename ''' + QUOTENAME(table_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(column_name) +  ''',''' + replace(column_name,' ','') + ''',''column'''
from        information_schema.columns 
where       table_catalog = 'dmarkovitz'
        and column_name like '% %'
```

---

```
exec sp_rename '[t1].[another col]','anothercol','column'
exec sp_rename '[t1].[yet another col]','yetanothercol','column'
exec sp_rename '[t2].[also a col]','alsoacol','column'
```

---

```
select      table_name,column_name
from        information_schema.columns 
where       table_catalog = 'dmarkovitz'
        and table_name in ('t1','t2')
```

---

```
+------------+---------------+
| table_name | column_name   |
+------------+---------------+
| t1         | col           |
+------------+---------------+
| t1         | anothercol    |
+------------+---------------+
| t1         | yetanothercol |
+------------+---------------+
| t2         | alsoacol      |
+------------+---------------+
| t2         | col           |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: What is `table_catalog = 'dmarkovitz'`? I select from `information_schema.columns `, which returns a empty table.

Comment: I've created this example on a local DB named dmarkovitz :-) change it as needed